# 20.04 Display issues - seems not refreshing exactly with Intel UHD 620

Tags: 20.04, kernel, display

I would appreciate some help with my HP Elitebook X360 with Intel UHE 620 graphics

Since I've been using this device I've sometimes had issues (depending on the kernel. The internal display seems not to refresh correctly.

Some examples:

1. At the login screen if I push the mouse to some moves I see a mouse arrow everywhere I stopped with the mouse.
2. If I type my login I don't see anything being typed on the display, but I do get logged in. If I hover over the login field with the mouse I suddenly see that I typed something.
3. When logged in after using a pull-down menu in (e.g. Librecad) the menu stays on the screen until I hover over it with the mouse, then it's gone.
4. If I push at the dash-icon then about 95% of the screen will not update/refresh until I hover with the mouse from the top to the bottom of the display. Then it will be refreshed.

This **ONLY** appears on the internal display. On an external display mirrored via HDMI there is NO PROBLEM at all.

Over the last 2 years I've been coping with the problem by waiting for the next kernel or the next after that one, while staying at the last working kernel.

But now I am waiting so much time by using kernel 5.8.0-63 where I still have NO issues.

I am actually using Ubuntu 20.04.4 with display driver i915
Or with dual-boot I am using Windows with no problems.

Trying **any** later kernel than 5.8.0-63 I have these issues.
Today I tried an alpha of 22.04. as live-stick with kernel 5.15.0.18 and there are the same issues.

I hope someone can help me here. All my other Ubuntu problems I was able solve by finding solutions in the web, but this time I can't find anything... I only found some things with freezing displays...

If you tell me what you need, I would be happy to provide more info.

Here are the requested outputs WHEN bad:

`xrandr` (bad)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`uname -a` (bad)

```
Linux x360 5.13.0-40-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 4 09:38:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`inxi -F` (bad)

```
System:    Host: x360 Kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP EliteBook x360 1040 G6 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 857F v: KBC Version 60.44.00 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: HP v: R90 Ver. 01.12.20 
           date: 03/15/2022 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 33.5 Wh condition: 38.1/56.2 Wh (68%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8265U bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 818 MHz min/max: 400/1400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-40-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp108s0 state: up mac: dc:fb:48:52:47:57 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 390.79 GiB (41.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HBLR-000H1 size: 953.87 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 71.59 GiB used: 64.15 GiB (89.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 41.0 C mobo: 40.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 359 Uptime: 7m Memory: 14.99 GiB used: 2.62 GiB (17.5%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

`lsmod | grep i915` (bad, still problems):

```
i915                 2400256  9  
drm_kms_helper        253952  1 i915  
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm                   557056  9 drm_kms_helper,i915
video                  53248  1 i915`
```

Now I provide the files when OK (no problems):

`xrandr` (OK, no problems)

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1920x1080     60.03*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    40.02  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`uname -a` (OK, no problems)

```
Linux x360 5.8.0-63-generic #71~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 15 17:46:08 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`inxi -F` (OK, no problems)

```
System:    Host: x360 Kernel: 5.8.0-63-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP EliteBook x360 1040 G6 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 857F v: KBC Version 60.44.00 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: HP v: R90 Ver. 01.12.20 
           date: 03/15/2022 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 31.3 Wh condition: 38.1/56.2 Wh (68%) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-8265U bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 6144 KiB 
           Speed: 1068 MHz min/max: 400/1400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 900 2: 900 3: 900 4: 900 5: 901 6: 900 7: 900 8: 900 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio driver: sof-audio-pci 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-63-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi 
           IF: wlp108s0 state: up mac: dc:fb:48:52:47:57 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 390.76 GiB (41.0%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HBLR-000H1 size: 953.87 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 71.59 GiB used: 64.13 GiB (89.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p4 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 40.0 C mobo: 40.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 373 Uptime: 3m Memory: 15.00 GiB used: 2.79 GiB (18.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

`lsmod | grep i915` (ok, no problems):

```
i915                 2203648  8  
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 i915  
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915 
drm                   552960  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
video
i915                 2203648  8
drm_kms_helper        217088  1 i915
cec                    53248  2 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm                   552960  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
video                  49152  1
i915                   49152  1 i915
```

[More output as requested here](https://paste.debian.net/1239835/)

Comment: Carlos, do you see exactly the same problem, with exactly the same computer and software?
Would you be ok with editing the question with further info as it is requested (not in comments)?
This is essential for a fluid solution attempt.
Otherwise, you would better post a separate OP, even if very similar.

Comment: Please post in the OP the output of the following commands, under both conditions where you do not and you do see problems. It is expected that this list grows a few times, depending on your feedback, and only then turn into a real answer. `xrandr` `uname -a` `inxi -F` What do you see when using *only* the internal, and *only* the external monitor?
You can use `arandr` to easily select this.

Comment: It is very strange that neither `xrandr` or `inxi` show the external monitor, even if it is working. Please post the info I requested. All the same output as before, but under two conditions which are different from what you posted: 1) Using only the internal monitor (you could disconnect the external); 2) Using only the external monitor, as per selection (not what you called "bad"), to select this you can use `arandr`, tinker a bit and you will find it. Please use kernel 5.13.
Do you have only one HDMI port?

Comment: Related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204800, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968243/xrandr-does-not-show-hdmi-at-all, https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=302086

Comment: Sorry, when doing those files NO external Display was connected. At the moment I am in a hospital for some days (hopefully only 4 or 5...). Here I don t have an ext. Display. So if it is nessesary to do the files while having an ext. Display connectet, I can provide those files in a week or so.. What I called "bad" means there are the problems visible - even without an ext. Display connected

Comment: Are both cases with no ext monitor, and only changing kernel?
I suggest you edit the question.
Make it easy for the readers, so they don't have to put together Question+Comments.

Comment: Ok, thank you - question edited. Yes, both cases were with no external Monitor. The only change was the kernel. That s why I think, the kernel should be responsible for my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I installed a fresh [Ubuntu Voyager](https://voyagerlive.org/) 22.04 with kernel 5.15.0-43 and had the same problems, but then I installed the latest kernel 5.19.0 via [Mainline GUI](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) and wow: no problems anymore!

I'm very happy (but had to wait for a long time!)

Regards,
Michael

P.S.: I didn't try any kernel between those two.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try tinkering with the driver configuration, with a few actions.

1. Create file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/i915.conf`
   with the following contents ([ref](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1737614&sid=40f40f41801da66abe9345caf2078f83#p1737614))

   ```
    Section "Device"
       Identifier "Device0"
       Driver "intel"
    EndSection
   ```

   Log out and back in.
2. Add option ([ref](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1737569&sid=40f40f41801da66abe9345caf2078f83#p1737569))

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.alpha_support=1"
   ```

   with `nano /etc/default/grub`, save the file, run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

In the meantime, please post *in the OP* the output of the following commands, with only the internal monitor plugged, and with kernels 5.8 and 5.13.

```
$ lsmod | grep i915
$ modinfo i915
$ lspci -knn | grep i915 -B3
```

**Related**:

1. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics

Comment: ok, I did 1. and 2. and I created the outputfiles of the three commands. What do you mean with "post in the OP". Do you mean "post in the original Post"? That is not possible, because there is an error by using more than 30k characters. Thats why I use a new answer for it. I tried around very much to get the output in in the format, which is more useful here, but sadly with no success...

Comment: @Michael - For posting long data in the question, you could upload it to pastebin, and then add the link in the question. It si not recommended to add that info as an answer.
See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253162/what-is-an-op-when-referring-to-stack-exchange

Comment: btw, I didn t have the directory /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d so I had to create it first.

Comment: That didn t work for me so I rolled back (deleted the /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/i915.conf) and in Grub I deleted  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.alpha_support=1")

Comment: Today I did a Firmware-update from 1.12 to 1.20 but sadly no change with my graphic issues... And I also tried Ubuntu 22.04 via usb-drive - no change also... Anyone with a new idea???

Comment: still the same problems. Any new idea?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like there is a problem with the **Panel Self Refresh** feature, which is meant to save power (by only refreshing the parts of the screen that are dirty)

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/696835/350793 for the solution

Comment: I tried this out, because I still have my Ubuntu 20.04 via Multiboot. But that didn't help also.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an issue with the upper 1/4 of my screen and was looking for a solution for months. I tried more than 10 other distros with the same or even much worse issues. I always thought about nvidia having issues but not about the intel card.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add the parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=4` to the kernel in `/etc/default/grub`

Source: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/intel/-/issues/5569

Comment: thanks, but that didn t help for me...